# Failed to get convolution algorithm

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

im trying to train a convolutional network, i will omit the part of the code that import and create folders for the pictures and clases, now this is the main code of the net, this example was taken from the book "deep learning in python" from François Collet

```
from keras import layers
from keras import models
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1177, activation='softmax'))

from keras import optimizers
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
metrics=['acc'])

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(NEW_DATA_DIR, target_size=(150, 150), batch_size=10,class_mode='categorical')

history = model.fit_generator(
train_generator,
steps_per_epoch=100,
epochs=30)
```

and then i get this error

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/mimus/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:3066: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
Epoch 1/30

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-380fa4b50355> in <module>
      2 train_generator,
      3 steps_per_epoch=100,
----> 4 epochs=30)

~/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1416             use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1417             shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1418             initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1419 
   1420     @interfaces.legacy_generator_methods_support

~/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
    215                 outs = model.train_on_batch(x, y,
    216                                             sample_weight=sample_weight,
--> 217                                             class_weight=class_weight)
    218 
    219                 outs = to_list(outs)

~/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight)
   1215             ins = x + y + sample_weights
   1216         self._make_train_function()
-> 1217         outputs = self.train_function(ins)
   1218         return unpack_singleton(outputs)
   1219 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2713                 return self._legacy_call(inputs)
   2714 
-> 2715             return self._call(inputs)
   2716         else:
   2717             if py_any(is_tensor(x) for x in inputs):

~/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in _call(self, inputs)
   2673             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals, run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   2674         else:
-> 2675             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
   2676         return fetched[:len(self.outputs)]
   2677 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1437           ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(
   1438               self._session._session, self._handle, args, status,
-> 1439               run_metadata_ptr)
   1440         if run_metadata:
   1441           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    526             None, None,
    527             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 528             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    529     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
    530     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to

UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node conv2d_1/convolution}}]]
     [[{{node loss/mul}}]]
```

im using python 3.6, tensorflowgpu 1.13.1, kerasgpu 2.2.4, cudatoolkit 10.0.130, cudnn 7.3.1, numpy 1.16.5. i really hope you can helpme to solve this, thank you in advance

edit:

using nvidia-smi i get this

```
NVIDIA-SMI 430.26       Driver Version: 430.26       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2060    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   52C    P8    19W / 170W |   5895MiB /  5931MiB |     24%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1305      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            20MiB |
|    0      1356      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          51MiB |
|    0      1556      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           123MiB |
|    0      1703      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          74MiB |
|    0      2816      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       3MiB |
|    0     10133      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       3MiB |
|    0     18578      C   .../mimus/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/bin/python  5605MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Are you getting any output by running `nvidia-smi` in your terminal? What driver version it is showing up there?

Comment: the driver is Driver Version: 430.26  i edit the post whit the nvidia-smi info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that my gpu have not enough ram for the complexity of the net, this can be solved by trying a smaller model, thank you all